# What is the name of the following lemma?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory

I thought that the lemma

**Lemma:** Let $f \in L^1_{loc}$. Assume that for all $\phi \in \mathscr{D}$, $\int f\phi = 0$. Then $f = 0$.

had been given the name of a famous mathematician, but I can't remember. How do you call this lemma?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: Very nice, on the link, I found the name I couldn't remember, it's du Bois-Reymond! I think I have seen this lemma with the name "du Bois-Reymond's Lemma" (maybe in french). If you convert your comment in an answer, I'll accept it!